# push and pop in nasm with stack

Tags: assembly, nasm

im doing the tutorial lessons and somethings here in the code i dont understand, maybe could anyone help me? i will appreciate about your help.

firstly the function sprint will be called, and in the 'sprint' function will edx,ecx,ebx,eax step by step be pushed onto the stack , and then the function 'slen' will be called , and the 'ebx' will be again pushed on the stack, i dont understand this step, ebx is already on the stack , as i know that 'ebx' is now the second last one on the stack after eax after sprint function is called. 
im wondering if there is 2 stacks here? or not 
Could any one please explain for me ? im would be very thankfull .

Best regard

> functions.asm

```
;------------------------------------------
; int slen(String message)
; String length calculation function
slen:
push    ebx
mov     ebx, eax

nextchar:
cmp     byte [eax], 0
jz      finished
inc     eax
jmp     nextchar

finished:
sub     eax, ebx
pop     ebx
ret


;------------------------------------------
; void sprint(String message)
; String printing function
sprint:
push    edx
push    ecx
push    ebx
push    eax
call    slen

mov     edx, eax
pop     eax

mov     ecx, eax
mov     ebx, 1
mov     eax, 4
int     80h

pop     ebx
pop     ecx
pop     edx
ret


;------------------------------------------
; void exit()
; Exit program and restore resources
quit:
mov     ebx, 0
mov     eax, 1
int     80h
ret '
```

> Blockquote
>   helloworld-inc.asm

```
; Hello World Program (External file include)
; Compile with: nasm -f elf helloworld-inc.asm
; Link with (64 bit systems require elf_i386 option): ld -m elf_i386 helloworld-inc.o -o helloworld-inc
; Run with: ./helloworld-inc

%include        'functions.asm'                             ; include our external file

SECTION .data
msg1    db      'Hello, brave new world!', 0Ah              ; our first message string
msg2    db      'This is how we recycle in NASM.', 0Ah      ; our second message string

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

mov     eax, msg1       ; move the address of our first message string into EAX
call    sprint          ; call our string printing function

mov     eax, msg2       ; move the address of our second message string into EAX
call    sprint          ; call our string printing function

call    quit            ; call our quit function
```

Comment: A function should save all registers that may be used by it or by functions that it calls.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with C? I only see assembly.

Comment: but ebx is already pushed onto the stack after sprint is called , and then in the function 'slen' it will be pushed again onto the stack, so it means on the stack there are 2 ebx's now? im curious about that :(

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: no, most calling conventions have some call-clobbered registers that functions are free to use without saving, so small functions aren't bloated with push/pop.  (In 32-bit x86, typically `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` are call-clobbered in the Linux SysV calling convention and all the major calling conventions used on Windows like `cdecl`, `vectorcall`, `stdcall`, etc.).

Comment: This may be the Irvine32 calling convention, where an arg is passed in `eax`, and all registers are call-preserved (except the return value in `eax`).  `sprint` could delay saving its caller's `ebx` until after `slen` returns, but there would be no advantage to doing that.  (And it would actually be worse.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions are independent (both are meant as public API functions). It's just coincidence that `sprint` calls `slen` internally, the `slen` can't assume it was called from `sprint` and the `ebx` is already preserved by it, it may be called as directly from user code, where the `ebx` may be not stored in stack.

So both functions follow the calling convention (the one the author of code picked, I don't know them from head, nor I want to guess which one it is, but if you are in linux and building elf32, <s>it's probably the standard linux 32b calling convention</s> (wrong guess, looks like Irvine32 lib calling convention, preserving all registers except `eax` which may return value, thanks to Peter Cordes for comments)). That means that both functions independently must preserve some registers to conform the convention, and only some registers may be freely modified and returned in modified state.

> as i know that 'ebx' is now the second last one on the stack after eax after sprint function is called

And that's not true either. The "stack" is just ordinary computer memory, just like your `.data` and `.bss` sections. It's just another reserved memory for your app process. What makes it somewhat special is value in register `esp`, which points to the "top of the stack".

Now when you do `push ebx`, the instruction will write 32 bit value in register `ebx` into computer memory at address `esp-4` (32 bit = 4 bytes, that's why `push` moves the stack pointer by -4 in 32b mode), and will also update the `esp` to point to that location (i.e. `esp -= 4`).

One of your misconceptions is "ebx is stored", if you will re-read that description above, you can notice there's no information in stack memory noting, that the value originated from `ebx`. And indeed if you will execute as next instruction `pop eax`, that value will be restored into register `eax` without any problem, and the `esp += 4`, causing in total similar effect as `mov eax,ebx`, but through stack memory (much slower than direct `mov`).

Another misconception is "second last after eax". The `call` instruction itself will push return address to stack, so inside `slen` after `push ebx` the stack contains values: "ebx", return address into sprint at next instruction after `call slen`, "eax", "ebx".

Don't hesitate to use instruction reference guide to verify what exactly particular instruction does, like:

- [`push`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html)
- [`pop`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_248.html)
- [`call`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html)
- [`ret`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html)

It's common even for seasoned asm programmer to verify any assumption about particular instruction, especially when flags are involved, or implicit register usage like with `mul/div/lods/stos/xlatb/...`. Don't guess just by name of instruction, some of them are lot more tricky than common sense would expect.

Also it's lot lot lot lot more easier to just fire this code in debugger, step over instructions, and see yourself how the `esp` and stack memory content evolves (that would clear the second part of this answer about how exactly `push/pop` works).

Comment: could i ask one more question? 
after slen is called will nextchar: and finished be executed ?

Comment: If it is related to something in your original question or my answer (i.e. something is still not clear), then yes please, I have hard time to read my answers with "fresh eyes", so I may be omitting something what is "obvious" to me, while it deserves better explanation. If the question is quite unrelated (new one), you may consider googling it, or posting separate question if googling fails, still for my curiosity feel free to post it here in comment, but my answer may be just "google this and that" in worst case.

Comment: hm, that's sort of related, yet not, and tricky to answer... pulling me toward in-depth kind of, which will be long... basically all of them `slen:`, `nextchar:` and `finished:` are labels marking particular memory address spot, known to the assembler during compile time. They don't produce any CPU instruction, so they can't be executed in "literally" sense, only instructions like `push / mov / cmp` will be executed. But the CPU executes the next instruction (unless you told it to jump somewhere else), so yes, the code will fall through `push @slen:` -> `mov` -> `cmp @nextchar:` -> ...

Comment: As this is NASM, I would suggest to use "local labels" for the internal ones, i.e. `.nextchar:` instead of `nextchar:`. The local label is defined as `<last_global_label>.<local_label>`, i.e. then the `.nextchar` inside `slen:` defines full label `slen.nextchar:`. But can be used by shortened form `.nextchar` inside `slen:` block (up till next global label). The advantage of this is less pollution of global symbols, allowing to use local labels `.nextchar:` for several different functions, without name collision, and also easier to read source, knowing the label is local.

Comment: no it was the question for above code  but i got it now , thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: But it may get messy when you will start to jump to the local ones from different block by using their full name, like doing `jmp slen.nextchar` from some completely different function, then the notion of "this is only local label" while reading `slen:` part of source may be misleading. So rather don't mix that and keep the public/internal API clean, using only public labels as entry points from different blocks.... if you ever plan to write anything medium+ complex in assembly, which is not a good idea any way, C++ project using only performance-critical tiny asm funcs is usually superior.

Comment: Common newcomers mistake is to forget to add `ret` instruction at end of their subroutine. When they proof-read their source code, they visually see through indentation and labels usage that the procedure *"did end"*, but the CPU doesn't care, it will execute the next instruction, whatever happens to be in following memory, so it takes some "enforcement" to learn brain to look for real code-flow changer instruction, like `ret / jmp / ...` and not rely on source indentation/labels occurrence, those are not visible to the CPU during runtime.

Comment: This is like the Irvine32 calling convention or something. `slen` takes a pointer arg in `eax`, not the stack (like i386 SysV does).  Treating `ebx` as call-preserved is normal, but not `ecx` and `edx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thinking how I wrote that answer, I didn't actually read the `slen` code at all, reading the beginning of `sprint` and question was enough to produce the answer. Yes, it's obviously some custom calling convention of tutorial author (but you are wrong about `ebx` in `slen`, actually the argument is in `eax` (!) and the `ebx` would be modified without `push/pop` ... would made lot more sense the other way around, but seems like also `sprint` is taking first arg in `eax`).

Comment: @Ped7g: I rewrote my previous comment after you read it because I noticed I had it backwards.  It looks like Irvine32, where the functions like WriteInt take their arg in `eax` >.<.  And BTW, it's not that weird to use the return-value register as the first arg.  Many RISC ISA calling conventions do that, e.g. ARM32-bit returns in `R0` and passes args in `R0-R3` (and R4-R15 are call-preserved).

Comment: @PeterCordes It's still bloated, I agree... now I did check the `sprint` further, and there is `pop     eax` `mov     ecx, eax` ... well.. :)

Comment: I also like the `ret` after the `sys_exit` (which is on Linux is guaranteed not to fail / return an error BTW).  And yeah, `push/pop` `eax` around `slen` is just silly.  This code makes the worst choices.  slen could be smaller (but even slower) if it did `push eax` / ... / `sub eax, [esp]` / `add esp, 4` instead of save/restoring a reg.  And `sprint` should obviously just `mov ecx,eax` before `slen` to take advantage of the call-preserved reg it just saved.  Or it should inline the strlen...